# Reel JS jQuery Plugin, iPad, slow loading images with thumbnail images

Tags: jquery, jquery-reel

We are using Reel JS for a 360 viewer we developed. 
We made it so that we have multiple thumbnails on the page and the user can select a thumbnail and a new Reel JS 360 viewer populates the page.

We are having issues on the iPad though.  When we try to switch between image sequences the iPad tends to choke or stall halfway through loading the images to the Reel JS 360 viewer. We are using a first generation iPad.
We are using hidden input fields to call the image sequence and loading the images into a placeholder. So all the images are not loaded to the page on page load.

On an Motorola Xoom tablet running Android, the image sequences load completely and fairly quickly.

Can anyone enlighten us on why on the iPad the image loader chokes?  is there something wrong with our JS?  The code works fine on Android Tablets and our desktops, but not on the iPad.

Our test page is here: http://www.dmns.org/test/jquery-360/index4.html

I have not posted any code because I don't exactly know if it is a code issue or just a limitation of the iPad, so I would like to see if anyone else could test it on an iPad and help us with any insight or thoughts.  If you absolutely need me to I can post all of our code. But I just thought someone viewing the source and analyzing it would be easier and better than me trying to put a bunch of code in this page.

Thanks in advance.